# What do R-rated and X-rated mean here?

Tags: metaphors

From [a course website for Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus](http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/385/index.html)

> Recommended Reading: R-Rated
>
> - Stochastic Differential Equations: An Introduction with Applications (6th edition) by B. Oksendal
> - Brownian Motion by P. Morters and Y. Peres
>
> Recommended Reading: X-Rated
>
> - Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion by D. Revuz and M. Yor
> - Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus by I. Karatzas and S. Shreve

I was wondering what R-rated and X-rated mean here? I only know a little that they are normally used for film ratings. But I suspect the reference books are rated according to their rigorousness and/or difficulty?

Comment: Perhaps *soft-core* and *hard-core* à la porn?

Comment: @bib: Which one is soft and which hard?

Comment: R is milder (soft) than X (hard)

Comment: Why not ask the instructor? (Listed as Professor Steve Lalley)

Comment: @JLG: I wish he were my instructor.

Comment: He gives his e-mail address on that link. Why not try asking him? It is an odd usage of a rating system. Maybe he is just being clever.

Comment: Sounds like a cheesy joke made my an American in allusion to film ratings, yes. I'd be very surprised if a book on stochastic calculus were actually sexually explicit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To interpret what is meant here, I think you have to consider a synonym of X-rated: *hard core*.

I would think that an “X-rated” book on stochastic modeling, then, would be “hard core.” In other words: chock full of intense math, and not very friendly toward the casual hobbyist. Another way to say this might be, “not for the faint of heart.” I can imagine someone issuing a warning: “Don't buy this book if you skipped the prerequisite course.” I'd expect such a text to be on the opposite side of the spectrum of where I'd find [*Math for Dummies*](http://www.dummies.com/store/Education/Math.html), which, to extend the metaphor, would be a G-rated book.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's a joke on the R (restricted) and X (adult) cinema classifications.

It means the first two books are moderately complicated and the last two are much more intimidating. The term hard-core, also from the adult entertainment industry, is also used.